Which CAS can do basic non-commutative differential algebra?
This is a repost of my question at MSE from 7 months ago, to which I haven't been able to find an answer yet.
I am looking for a CAS (possibly incl. additional packages/libraries) that can compute generic non-commutative differential expressions.
Let me illustrate what I mean by two examples.
Let $(R,\partial)$ be a generic non-commutative differential ring (i.e. $\partial$ is a derivation on $R$), say of characteristic 0 for simplicity.
Let $f \in R$ be an abstract (or generic if you prefer) element. Then it should be able to express
$$
\partial^2(1+f)^2
$$
as
$$
2 \partial^2(f) + \partial^2(f) f + 2 \partial(f)^2 + f \partial^2(f)
$$
and
$$
(f\partial)^2 f
$$
as
$$
f \partial(f)^2 + f^2 \partial^2 (f),
$$
where the elements $f$ and $\partial^k(f)$ are treated as black boxes.
In particular, the elements $\partial^k(f)$ are not assumed to commute with each other in any way for differing values of $k \geq 0$.

I have added an answer mentioning Cadabra to your post on MSE.

@KasperPeeters: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for! Feel free to post an answer here as well!

Does this fit your desires? This is Mathematica code:
D[(1 + f[t]) ** (1 + f[t]), {t, 2}]

Out:=(1 + f[t]) ** f''[t] + 2 f'[t] ** f'[t] + f''[t] ** (1 + f[t])

Operation ** is non-commutative multiplication.

Yes, this seems to work as desired! Thank you! I was not aware of the non-commutative multiplication option in Mathematica! Quick question, though. Is there a way for Mathematica to better group the terms as in my answer for improved overview of the terms?

Also, can Mathematica compute explicitly the operator $(f\partial)^3$? This is equally important for me.

@M.G. You can install the package NCAlgebra https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~ncalg/ and then use NCExpand

@M.G. You can also use dot product: D[(1 + f[t]) . (1 + f[t]), {t, 2}]. As long as the objects are not matrices or lists, it will behave like **.

This looks great! Could you please also include in your answer a code example for calculating the operator $(\partial f)^3$? I'm not that experienced in Mathematica and I'm still trying to get the hang of it.

@M.G. I am not sure what this operator is doing and in what sense it is different from $f^3\partial^3$ or $\partial^3 f^3$.

@Annix: It's neither. It's $(f \partial) (f \partial) (f \partial)$. See my question for the simpler expression $(f\partial)^2$ applied to $f$, i.e. $(f \partial)(f\partial) f = (f\partial)(f f') = f (f' f' + f f'') = f(f')^2 + f^2 f''$.

@M.G. I suggest you to ask at Mathematica.SE

@M.G. In any case you can use the Nest function to repeat an operation n times.
